# pmf for a function of random variables

Tags: probability

I have an independent sequence of random variables  such that P($X_n = \pm1) = \frac{1-2^{-n}} {2} $
 and P($X_n = 2^ k)=2^{-k}$ for k = n+1,n+2,...
Define a new sequence of random variables by $Y_n = X_n$ if $X_n = \pm1$
$Y_n = 0$ otherwise.
Find P($Y_n = y)$

How to do this?
I have so far proven $X_n$ and $Y_n$ to be tail equivalent. I have to prove Lyapunov's condition for sum of $Y_n$ which I will be able to if I can find E($Y_n)$ but that is where I am stuck.

Comment: There is so very little to be done to answer this question that one hardly knows what to write in response. Perhaps you could help us out by explaining the point of this exercise: what is it helping you to learn? What have you tried so far in your efforts to solve it? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thank you for the edits (+1).  You might be overthinking this.  Start by considering the possible values of $y$.  Yes, $y$ could be any real number--but based on the definition of $Y_n$ which values of $y$ do you need to examine?  The probabilities of two of those values are given to you immediately by the definition of $X_n$.  The rest is straightforward to work out... .

Comment: Since $Y_n$ takes $X_n$ when $X_n$ = $\pm1$ so P($Y_n = \pm1) = \frac { 1-2^{-n}} {2}$, is that correct?

Comment: The only way that could be incorrect would be if there is some other circumstance in which $Y_n$ could equal $1$ (or $-1$). After you convince yourself of the impossibility of this (by looking again at the definitions of $Y_n$ and $X_n$ and assuming $n\ge 1$), then obviously $\Pr(Y_n \notin \{1,-1\}) = 1 - 2\frac{1-2^{-n}}{2} = 2^{-n}$. What does that tell you?